# Python alternative of agent.setContext()

Tags: dialogflow-es

In node.js we can set context using `agent.setContext()`, what will be python alternative of using this way?

Currently I am using below code to set new context:

```
res = {
    "fulfillmentText = "This is a test",
    "outputContexts": [
        {
            "name": "projects/project_id/agent/sessions/session_id/contexts/your_context",
            "lifespanCount": 5,
            "parameters": {
                "foo": "bar",
                "foo1": "bar1"
            }
        }
    ],
}
return res
```

**Is there any simpler way?**
Thanks in advance.

**Note :** It seems like node.js have `dialogflow-fulfillment` library to ease up the things. Is there any similar fulfillment library for python as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Node.js `dialogflow-fulfillment` library is owned and maintained by Dialogflow/Google.  There is no "official" Dialogflow Python fulfillment library but there are a couple community efforts you can fork:

- Flask extension: https://github.com/treethought/flask-assistant
- Response generation helper: https://github.com/pragnakalp/dialogflow-webhook-response-libary-in-python

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard python fulfillment library at this time. Sounds like an opportunity for you!

The format for setting output contexts looks correct, and isn't really much more difficult than the equivalent in JavaScript. How much simpler do you want it?

Comment: haha.. wish i could do that! yeah i wanted to know if i'm doing it correctly. i'll write a function to make it simpler.